# ImageBase + SizeOfHeaders will jump at the section table

Tags: windows, assembly, portable-executable

I was reading a tutorial on PE and it says

> Go to the section table either by adding ImageBase to SizeOfHeaders

but SizeOfHeaders is

> The size of all headers+section table

so if we add SizeOfHeaders to ImageBase won't we jump at the sections rather than the table?

Comment: Maybe the tutorial has an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SizeOfHeaders` indeed is the size of the entire header, including the DOS stub.

To get the address of the section table, first get the address of the optional header, and add `FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader`.

Comment: So given ImageBase, it will be ImageBase+PE Header(Signature+FileHeader+Optional Header)... and given the address of Optional Header, I should add FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader, right?

Answer (score 2):

`SizeOfHeaders` is not used to find out the position of the section table, even if they might match in some files (but I don't expect so).

Here's how it's done in the Windows headers (and thus the system loader):

```
#define IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION( ntheader ) ((PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)        \
    ((ULONG_PTR)(ntheader) +                                            \
     FIELD_OFFSET( IMAGE_NT_HEADERS, OptionalHeader ) +                 \
     ((ntheader))->FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader   \
    ))
```

Note that the actual value of `SizeOfOptionalHeader` is not checked; it can be very big or even negative - some malware uses it trick to fool analyzing tools.

See [here](http://code.google.com/p/corkami/wiki/PE#SizeOfOptionalHeader) for more details and even nastier tricks.

Comment: The link you provided was great.. Thanks